# Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 cannot change window border theme

Tags: gnome, themes, 13.10, gnome-tweak-tool

I installed Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 and when I change GTK theme using Gnome Tweak Tool, only theme of widgets changes, theme of Window border remains same.

Can somebody help me to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the solution linked by user62716: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=167309, let me type it out here.

```
cd /usr/share/pyshared/gtweak/
sudo gedit gsettings.py
```

Insert this before line 37:

```
if schema_name == "org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences":
    schema_filename = schema_name + ".gschema.xml"
```

Now it should look like:

```
def __init__(self, schema_name, schema_dir=None, schema_filename=None, **options):
    if not schema_dir:
        schema_dir = gtweak.GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR
    if schema_name == "org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences":
        schema_filename = schema_name + ".gschema.xml"
    if not schema_filename:
        schema_filename = schema_name + ".gschema.xml"
```

Save, and exit. Open Tweak Tool, go to "Theme", and for "Current theme", select your desired theme.

Answer (score 3):

To change to theme *Adwaita*, open a terminal and do:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme Adwaita
```

Source: [How can you change the GTK Theme and Window Decorations separately in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361422/)

Comment: This does only work if theme is in `/usr/share/themes/`. `~/.themes/` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution to this problem here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=167309

See post #10.