# How can you change the GTK Theme and Window Decorations separately in Unity?

Tags: unity, compiz, themes, customization, 13.10

I'm trying to mix and match a GTK theme with a different Window Decoration, but I cant see where this can be done. The Unity-Tweak-Tool changes the two in tandem, but this is not necessarily what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to change the **Window theme** and the **GTK theme** separately using the gsettings command, Ubuntu Tweak or gnome-tweak-tool.

---

### [Gsettings](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/gsettings.1.html)

There are two schemas, for the gtk theme is **org.gnome.desktop.interface** & for the window theme is **org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences**.

In this example I will set the gtk-theme to Ambiance and the Window-theme to Radiance.

**1)** Open a Terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

- `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Ambiance`
- `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme Radiance`

#### The result in Nautilus:

[image]

---

### [Ubuntu-Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/)

To install ubuntu-tweak you can add this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Etualatrix/+archive/ppa).

**1)** Open a Terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`

**2)** Open the Ubuntu-Tweak and go to **Tweaks -> Theme.**

[image]

[image]

---

### [Gnome-Tweak-Tool](https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeTweakTool)

To install the gnome-tweak-tool

**1)** Open a Terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

- `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

**2)** Open the gnome-tweak-tool application and go to **Theme.**

[image]

**NOTE:** In this application the window-theme is named as **Current Theme**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution (`gsettings`) does not seem to work as of Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: changing window theme in ubuntu tweak doesn't work.

Comment: ubuntu-tweak not found in 16.04
(sorry, cannot comment the previous answer)