# Gnome, can't change window border or theme

Tags: unity, gnome, themes

I just now changed from unity to gnome. I got it from the ubuntu app store, and I decided to remove unity to avoid conflicts. I thought it was going well until I noticed that the side bar when you open up the app launch is in the middle of the screen. Also the window border and theme will not change when I use the gnome tweak tool.I can change the Icons, cursor, and the GTK, even changing between the default window borders doesn't work. I can see them listed as options, in the shell themes as well, but I can't change them. I don't know what happened and can't change a thing, I need help. Using ubuntu 14.04 if that helps at all. As you can tell I'm a newb...

Comment: This worked in 13.10 and might for you:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/361335/ubuntu-gnome-13-10-cannot-change-window-border-theme